# Where to look for DB file after update-database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity

I created domain classes and their DB tables representations using entity framework. Using migrations seed method I created `init` data. In console window, I use `Update-Database` command to create db and seed data. Now, I don't know where to find this database file, and how to attach in server explorer.

My App.config connection string looks

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDbContext;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDbContext.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I look up in `App_Data` folder, and tried to attach DB using server explorer, but I don't know where to browse to add. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of sql server express are you using ? If you install sql server managements studio, you can connect using the same connection string right click on the database and find out where the physical files are.

Comment: For my the files are here : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

Comment: Found it now inside sqlexpress object explorer. How can I force update-database to use App_Data folder, cause I want to copy db to that location

Comment: You have to create your database over there first, the connection string is also impacted because now it really points to the location where you found the files.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly and you are looking for the physical location of the files in Sql server express 2008 R2 then you can find them here :

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

I am not using sql server express myself so the number 10 might be different for you.

If you want to move it to app_data take a look at this :

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/441590/How-to-add-existing-database-in-app-data-folder-in